# Automating the Asterisk IVRs (Inbound/Outbound dialplans) in Java

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, fastagi

I am new to Asterisk. I need to create outbound/inbound dial plans from the user-interface/DB config and run various campaigns in the asterisk. The UI will abstract the user from the asterisk server in gathering various inputs required for the outbound dial plans to run. The idea is to automate the inbound and outbound IVR and eliminate manual intervention. Is this feasible at all? If so how and if not any other way? I saw Asterisk-Java but not sure how to proceed with that (FastAGI and AMI). 
thanks
-Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Any task you can imagine can be done on asterisk. It have open source and you can extened it as needed.

You need read asterisk-related book like "Asterisk the future of telephony" and read documentation for Asterisk-java on its site.

After that you can use asterisk dialplan and/or asterisk realtime architecture to manage your IVRs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try my framework Astive Toolkit. Its new compare to asterisk-java but is fresh and brings a lot of interesting features.

http://astivetoolkit.org